# Issues getting EV SSL certificate to work on Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I've gotten SSL to work on Apache servers and on a client's Nginx server. However, I am having issues with my EV SSL certificate installation. This is also on a server with a special character in the URL: `weöm.com`.

`weöm.com` is displayed as `xn--wem-tna.com` in browsers, which is fine. When I inspected my `.ca-bundle` that was emailed to me from COMODO, I saw my domain name rendered as `we\xC3\xB6m.com`, which made me think I have to generate my `.csr` and `.key` the same way.

Here's how I've been doing it (ran this command in Terminal):

`openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out weom.csr -keyout weom.key -subj "/serialNumber=000000000/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=US/postalCode=00000/ST=California/L=Cupertino/street=1 Loop Way/O=Apple Inc/OU=COMODO EV SSL/CN=we\xC3\xB6m.com"`

(I've replaced the serial number and other things with fake data in my example)

The code spits out a `.csr` and `.key` with the exact same data that my compiled `.crt` has and I cannot understand why I'm still getting this `SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch` error.

I've been wrangling with this for about a week, does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Proving more information...

Here is how I'm creating my master `.crt`:

`cat xn--wem-tna.com.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt >> cert_chain.crt`

This is the `default` file in my `sites-available` folder:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name xn--wem-tna.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate     cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key weom.key;

    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name xn--wem-tna.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: The subject of the certificate should contain the "real" hostname which is the punycode name, i.e. `xn--wem-tna.com`.

Comment: That's how it was initially, but I got that error. I'll try it again.

Comment: Yeah, there's no change in the error I get.

Comment: So you get this error message from apache? In this case it would be good to know your configuration because it means that the key you have configured with SSLCertificateKeyFile does not match the *first* certificate you have in SSLCertificateFile. Note that there might be multiple such configurations, so check them all.

Comment: No, I get this error from Nginx, I'm not using Apache for this server. I'll update my question with how I'm generating my `.crt`.

Comment: Then look at the nginx config, i.e. ssl_certificate_key must be the key for the *first* certificate in ssl_certificate. And with nginx there might also be multiple SSL configurations and you need to check them all.

Comment: If there were multiple configurations, would conflicts show up in error logs? Because, they don't. Also, I've never heard of the first certificate in an SSL also being the key. Can you link to where there's an example of that?

Comment: I did not say that the first certificate *is* the key (this would be impossible, a certificate is not a private key) but that it *should match* the key. You have the key in one file and the certificate + chain in the other file. And the certificate of the site must be the top certificate in this file, followed by the chain certificate(s) in the correct order.

Comment: Hey Steffan, are you aware of any tools that would allow me to visually compare differences in my certificates?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "visually compare differences" and why do you want to do it. What you actually need to do is [verify that the private key matches the certificate](https://www.google.com/search?q=verify+that+a+private+key+matches+a+certificate).

Comment: That is what I've been doing, with no results. I wanted to visually compare to see exactly what's wrong, instead of relying on hashes. I already know they don't match, I want to know why. Idk why this has been so difficult, but I've contacted another EV SSL provider to see if the certs they offer are stress-free.

Comment: Since key and cert are completely different things there is nothing in there you might compare apart from the modules. You might check with `openssl x509 -text -in certificate.crt` if you have the correct certificate at all on top of the cert file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah, forgot to update.

I got a refund and went with CertSimple. Emailed them questions Friday night, went through the entire process of obtaining an EV cert Saturday morning/afternoon, and had it on my server by 6pm (and that's only because I was out running errands).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that your KEY and CRT are different.

You can verify this by checking MD5 hashes on them:

`openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt | openssl md5`

`openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in privateKey.key | openssl md5`

Additionally I would change the order in the bundle CRT (cert_chain.crt),at the moment you have it this way:

> xn--wem-tna.com.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSAExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt

It should be:

cat xn--wem-tna.com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > cert_chain.crt

This is Official [Comodos Certificate Installation: NGINX](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1091/0/certificate-installation--nginx)

**What gets me worried is your comment at the beginning:**

If you have changed the key once your certificate had been issued you will need to invalidate it and apply for a new CRT with your new KEY and new CSR.

> weöm.com is displayed as xn--wem-tna.com in browsers, which is fine. When I inspected my .ca-bundle that was emailed to me from COMODO, I saw my domain name rendered as we\xC3\xB6m.com, which made me think I have to generate my .csr and .key the same way.